# Reply to a specific user in the comment section when there are multiple users with the-same name

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, comment-replies

There was a comment under a question and I wanted to reply to that comment then another user made a comment. The users both have the-same user name "Greg" and almost the-same rep and it was hard to distinguishing between them.

I wanted to reply to the first "Greg" but didn't know how to do this. I got this instead:

[image]

- How do you reply to one specific user when there are two different
  users with the-same name?
- Are the users with the-same username displayed in order based on the comments time?

I simply went with the first one displayed and don't know which user is notified.

**EDIT:**

With all the comments, it looks like the last user will get the notification. Why not link the user name displayed in the image above with the user-id so that make the user-id will be displayed when the mouse is over each one displayed. In that case, when you select a user to reply to, it will reply to that user-id instead of the user with the most recent comment?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)? The most recent "Greg" would be pinged. Doesn't say if there is a way to specify the other "Greg", AFAIK.

Comment: @yivi Just read that but it didn't address the questions in this question

Comment: I almost wanted to say thats not usefull here @yivi untill I saw this: _"Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @ john will match the most recent John."_

Comment: @AndréKool Ok. How about the image in my question, does it really matter which one is selected in this case or will it always be the most recent Greg? If not, are they are they displayed in most recent like the most recent receives the notification?

Comment: @Programmer It does answer the last bit of your question: _"don't know which user is notified_". Regarding the other questions, I do not think there is a way to specify one of the two "gregs". The latest "greg" to comment will be the one pinged.

Comment: @Programmer I imagine that the algorithm that selects names for the popup isn't smart enough to deal with this case.  It just gets a list of all unique users and puts their display name in a box.  Since there are 2 greg's, it shows you Greg twice.  But as to which is pinged, that is well covered by the linked question - the last one always is pinged.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That sucks when you can't reply to another user due to similar names. In that case, SO should link the username displayed with user-id then do the reply thing with user id instead of username since they are unique.

Comment: A similar problem exists in chat, which did see a [prototype](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268351/rfc-better-chat-mentions-a-prototype) to address this but it never made it into production. I'm not aware any work has been to overcome the same issue in comments on the Q/A-sites.

Comment: Now that this is a feature request, there is a duplicate from MSE: [How to reply to one user among two having same names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names).  There's also a host of linked duplicates and related questions on MSE.  So this is not a new concern

Comment: @psubsee2003 useful link. It now looks like a dup to me. Anyways, I hope it gets implemented.